# Replace Navteq maps by a free one in a car built-in GPS

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, navigation, opel

My car (Opel Zafira) have a built-in GPS with Navteq maps (SD 900 NAVI).

I wonder if it would be possible to update or upgrade the maps to an open source / free maps (like OSM).

Or is it possible to convert the OSM maps into the Navteq format?

Anybody tried this?

Comment: Can you give us more hints as the vendor/brand of the navigation system? I don't know a general solution, so it depends on the type of system...

Comment: @Mapper Opel called that option: SD 900 NAVI, but I do not know what is the real system behind. Some people on forum talked about a Bosh system, but nothing official.

Comment: Im guessing there was never a followup on a solution to this....

Comment: @Randy Navit is an active project http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit

Answer (score 1):

There is (currently) [no way for in-car navigation devices](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/PNA) to make use of OSM map packages. The problem is that they are very closed embedded systems and there is no documentation about the navi file formats or how the operating system can be supplied with alternative software.

As this situation is very sad, I highly recommend to start an petition on your car vendor to help you to extend the lifecycle of your car enterainment system:

1. Create free to use map packages from OSM data. The OSM community will be very happy in [assisting in such step](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact).
2. Provide full specs. about file format and testers so the OSM community can code converters. This worked very well for example on Garmin devices.

Another option would be if the Opel community would give the OSM (or any other reverse engeniering community) such devices and SD cards/CDs/... so they can try to crack the data format on their own.

All in all, any action will need somebody to start and manage such things :)

Answer (score 1):

NAVTEQ stores *maps* and *POI* (point of interest, like hospital,hotel,restaurant,bar,.....) in different file formats.

You may add your own POI spot(s) easily by editing your POI files (idx,url) which exist in your navigation DVD or your USB depending on your hardware, the format is described at the beginning lines(check the following picture), they are easy plain ASCII files describing a table with fixed bytes as columns.

In order to add a new POI just take a look at those already exist in your files!

The headers are very long so they can not be fitted here but I have took a picture from one of them (url extensions).
The idx is similar to url, do not panic if you hit with some weird symbols. just copy them and it will work!

[image: a Sample URL file]

There is a complete description on Navteq geometrical(map) format here :

https://www.scribd.com/document/269424945/Navteq-Data-Format-Extraction-Guide-Public

Sorry I did not find a free source, but it has a 30 days trail.

**Do not mistake url files with internet shortcut, the url I am talking about is a plain ASCII file which includes POI info**